# How many ways are there to draw at least one face card from a deck of cards?

Tags: combinatorics

From a standard deck of 52 cards, 5 cards are dealt and the order of the cards is unimportant. In how may ways can you receive at least one face card?

I understand that the answer is 1,940,952 ways which can be calculated by doing $52\choose5$ - $40\choose5$.

My question is why doesn't $12\choose1$ $51\choose4$ also work? I'm trying to choose a face card and then choose the four other cards from the rest of the deck, but it equals 2998800.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It doesn't work because you overcount hands with more than one face card.  For such a hand, you can't tell which one is the "special" face card counted by the $\binom {12}1$ term.  Thus hands with exactly $2$ face cards are counted twice, hands with exactly $3$ face cards are counted three times, and so on.

Comment: In line with the comment of @lulu, what **will work** is $$\left[ ~\binom{12}{1}\binom{40}{4} ~\right] + \left[ ~\binom{12}{2}\binom{40}{3} ~\right] + \left[ ~\binom{12}{3}\binom{40}{2} ~\right]$$ $$+ \left[ ~\binom{12}{4}\binom{40}{1} ~\right] + \left[ ~\binom{12}{5}\binom{40}{0} ~\right].$$